# Run launch file automatically in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, launch

I would like to have the possibility to run a .launch file without having to navigate to a project and folder and choose that file and right click and choose run.

It would also be nice if I could run tomcat without having to navigate to the server tab as you can see in screenshot [image]

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: In the launch configuration dialog in the _Common_ tab the launch configuration can be added to the favorites menu.